styled-components - typescript - Unsafe assignment of an error typed value
I'm working on application Next.js + Typescript.
I installed styled-components.
and wrote the file Card.styled.ts:
import styled from "styled-components";

export const StyledCard = styled.div`
  max-width: 20rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 0.1);
`;


Typescript alerting with a red line under the styles with the errors:
Unsafe assignment of an error typed value
Unsafe use of a(n) 'error' type typed template tag
I tried installing @types/styled-components didn't work.
styled-components version: 6.1.13

Changing the file name suffix to .tsx fixed it.
Expected: Card.styled.tsx
Actual: Card.styled.ts
